# Obtain the biggest circle which has all inner points close to given regions

Tags: geometry, algorithms

In $\mathbb{R}^2$, I've got various spots, which may either be points, lines or polygons (there will always be one point in $(0,0)$):

[Illustration of the spots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDP4m.png)

How can I find the biggest circle/disk (center always in $(0,0)$), whose inner points do not exceed a given distance $d_{max}>0$ to at least one of the spots?

---

### Edit

A smallest circle with radius $r=Max\left(\overline{P,(0,0)}\right)+d_{max}$ does not fit the needs, as there may be regions inside the circle, where the next "spot" may be further away than $d_{max}$:

[Illustration: Problem with smallest circle-approach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63IKm.png)

Comment: If $O$ and $R$ are resp. the center and the radius of a smallest covering circle of the union of your "spots" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallest-circle_problem), isn't your circle the circle with center $O$ and radius $R+d_{max}$ ?

Comment: @JeanMarie No, not necessarily: There might exist points within the circle, where the distance to the next "spot" (please forgive my english problems) exceeds $d_{max}$.

Comment: @skyking I am using a CAS. There I thought of "inflating" all of my regions by $d_{max}$, then build the union of all regions and finally search the minimal distance to $(0,0)$. This procedure is rather slow. Therefore I'd like to try other approaches or optimize mine... I also "feel", that a Voronoi-approach may be promising, but I've got no experience with that.

Comment: For me it is not in contradiction with the the definition "whose inner points do not exceed a given distance $d_{max}$ to at least one of the spots"...

Comment: @JeanMarie please see my edit.

Comment: I understand now, thanks. Then, it means that, if you denote by $D$ the dilated set of the set of spots $S$ with $d_{max}$ "amount of dilation", your circle has to be included in $D$. As a consequence, there will, in general, not exist a unique solution (think to $S$= a rectangle)